# HIve Create Json Array that not contains duplicate

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I want to create an array of jsons that not contain duplicate . I had used LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE to break the initial Array , and now i want to group the string json i received and create merged jsons based on a key. 
For example if i have :
Col1 :

```
{"key" : ke , "value" : 1 }
{"key" : ke , "value" : 2 }
{"key" : ke1 , "value" : 5 }
```

I would like to have

```
{"key" : ke , "value" : 3 }
{"key" : ke1 , "value" : 5 }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: This is not a valid JSON.

Comment: every string is on a different row in a column

Comment: String values should be qualified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      concat('{"key":"',jt.key,'","value":',sum(jt.value),'}')

from        mytable t
            lateral view json_tuple(Col1, 'key', 'value') jt as key,value

group by    jt.key
;
```

Comment: And if i want to add this in a more complex structure , with more columns , can i only use GROUP BY for a certain column ?

Comment: Please open a new question for that

Comment: str will be one row from the table ?

Comment: Yes, changed it now to `Col1`